# How can I Create app maker to GET or POST Requests to my Node-red?

Tags: postman, google-app-maker

So,I want to used App maker to create some app that sending data Get or Post request to my node-red. 
It's was look like Postman but I want to use it form google App maker. Any suggestions? 
(sorry about my bad english)

Answer (score 1):

You use server side scripts.  Please look at [this guide](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/rest/) which has example code for making HTTP requests to external APIs.